# Keeping all SQL Server logs

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I can not find my SQL Server logs for all days in the past. In only found for last 4 days. Is it because that I restarted the server and logs are dumped if the hosting server is restarted?

How can I keep entire logs?

I am using the GUI to view the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure  using SSMS GUI :

[image]

Make sure you have error logs set to manageable size.

Check MSDN : [Configure SQL Server Error Logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177285.aspx) and [kb 2199578](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2199578) for managing SQL Server error log.

EDIT:

Below is what we do in our PROD environments:

1. Recycle error logs using `master.sys.sp_cycle_errorlog` with a SQL Agent job.
2. If you need more than 99 days of log (since you mentioned in your comment - `The maximum is 99 which will be reached very soon`), you can use PowerShell to move the files to a safe location. I would doubt that you would need error logs past 99 days ! Just make sure that you keep them in a manageable size, else you it would be difficult for log viewer to open very large files.

Comment: I would add: create a SQL Agent job to cycle the ERRORLOG every day and set the number of errorlog files to the number of days you want to keep. Maximum is 99. The job should simply invoke `master.sys.sp_cycle_errorlog`. The same concept applies to the SQL Server Agent Errorlog

Comment: The maximum is 99 which will be reached very soon .

Comment: In around 99 days I would say. Do you need more than 99 days of ERRORLOG? I don't think so. In case, you can always copy the files elsewhere and keep them indefinitely.

Comment: @spaghettidba was adding that info already. Thanks !

Comment: @JavaMain see my updates above.